# "Missing file icon" is shown in the system tray when running showMessage with NoIcon on LXDE

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5, system-tray

I'm building an application which uses notifications, and which has an icon in the system tray

I'm using [`showMessage`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#showMessage) with the *icon* parameter set to [`NoIcon`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#MessageIcon-enum) and when the message is displayed the system tray icon changes from the icon that I have set for the application to this icon:

[image: system tray with missing icon file]

*This icon is used by my system to show that the file is missing*

I've tried setting the icon parameter to [`Information`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#MessageIcon-enum) instead which shows the letter "i" in both the message and in the system tray (while the message is shown), so there is no problem in this case

**When using `NoIcon` can I avoid seeing the missing icon while the message is shown and instead see my application icon in the system tray?**

Grateful for help!

---

My setup:

- Lubuntu 16.04 (uses **LXDE**)
- PyQt: 5.7.1 (same as the Qt version)

Code:

```
self.tray_icon.showMessage(
    "Application Name",
    "Message",
    icon=QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon.NoIcon,
    msecs=10*1000
)
```

Comment: Having the same problem for Qt 5.9.0

Comment: This problem is not seen on XFCE (4.12)

Comment: I confirm that the bug exists on Xfce 4.16 + Qt 5.11 and your solution still works. I also confirm that this issue is **not** reproducible on Windows